# object to array modification in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a object like this,

```
const obj = 
{
    "One": "1",
    "Two": "2",
    "Three": "3"
}
```

I want to convert this object in to an array, in this format,

```
const options = [
  { value: "1", label: "One" },
  { value: "2", label: "Two" },
  { value: "3", label: "Three" },
];
```

Can anybody help me how to do it in Javascript?

Comment: What did you try to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```js
const obj = 
{
    "One": "1",
    "Two": "2",
    "Three": "3"
}

const transform = data => Object.entries(data)
    .map(([label, value]) => ({label, value}))
    
    
console.log(transform(obj))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of Object.entries and .map

```js
const obj =
    {
        "One": "1",
        "Two": "2",
        "Three": "3"
    }

    const options = Object.entries(obj).map(e=>{
        return {value: e[1], label: e[0]}
    })
    
    console.log(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

const obj = {
"One": "1",
"Two": "2",
"Three": "3"
}

```
const arr = Object.entries(obj).map((element)=>{
    return {value: element[1], label: element[0]}
})

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.map` method of array to create a new object with the shape you desire.

Ex.

```
Object.keys(obj).map(prop => ({label: prop, value: obj[prop]}))
```

Answer (score 0):

*sounds like you need to use .map*

You can convert your obj -> map

*Example:*

> > **const yourObj = {    id: 1,   name: 'Fred', id: 2, name: 'Mark'  };**

**So, USE:**

> > **const objInMap = new Map(Object.entries(yourObj));**

this will be the result

> > ***console.log(objInMap)**; // -> {'id' => 1, 'name' => 'Fred' ; 'id' => 2, 'name' => 'Mark'}*